# What is a good way to display python dict data in OS X GUI?

Tags: python, macos, dictionary, tkinter

I’d like the ability to sort by each column, as well as narrow the output with range of values for certain column.

At first I thought this can be done in csv/json viewers but the problem with those is that I also need a button bound to certain python code (which retrieves the data).

I’m currently looking into tkinter, but then I read somewhere it's poorly optimized for OS X. Was wondering if there are better alternatives.

Comment: Take a look at pyQt5

Comment: if all you need is to view some simple data, tkinter is more than sufficient on OSX.